# How to find custom elements in form and replece them to inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqueryform

How to find all custom elements in form and convert it to inputs with same value?
Here is the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/irider89/jsL28xno/4/

```js
$(function() {
    $(".triggeredit-card-list").click(function() {
        var UsrName = $('.card-list-table').find('#nameEditable').html();
        console.log(UsrName);
        $('.card-list-tabe').find('#nameEditable').html('<input type="text" class="editable-table" name="editname" id="edittext" value="'+ UsrName +'" />');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="flip-scroll" class="table-responsive card-list-table">
    <table class="table table-custom">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Номер карты</th>
                <th>Ф.И.О.</th>
                <th>Дата выдачи</th>
                <th>Состояние</th>
                <th>Сумма на карте</th>
                <th>Категория</th>
                <th>Суточная норма</th>
                <th>Месячная норма</th>
                <th>Выбранная норма за месяц</th>
                <th>Вес карты</th>
                <th>Комментарий</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>5757427</td>
                <td class="" id="nameEditable">Петров Иван Иванович 1</td>
                <td>25.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>Дизель</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>26</td>
                <td id="monthValue">1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>69594894</td>
                <td id="nameEditable">Константинопольский Яков Аристархович</td>
                <td>27.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5757427</td>
                <td id="nameEditable">Петров Иван Иванович</td>
                <td>25.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-triggeredit triggeredit-card-list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Редактировать</button>
```

I need to convert to input ***Ф.И.О.*** and ***Выбранная норма за месяц***, but to put this values to the input.

Comment: ID should be unique!

Comment: for example, I want to find all id's nameEditable and convert them to inputs with the value, wich was been in this id. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same id? I suppose you should use class in this case.

Comment: you mean a text not a custom element, I posted an answer for it.

Comment: So basically you desire an edit-in-place

Answer (score 0):

its an example of one of your inputs, according to your jsFiddle

You should use `replaceWith` to replace the elemnt, html just changes the `innerHtml` of the element

```
$( "th:contains('Ф.И.О.')" ).replaceWith('<input value="Ф.И.О." />')
```

if you want just replace the content in `th` use

```
$( "th:contains('Ф.И.О.')" ).html('<input value="Ф.И.О." />')
```

In general it is

```
var itemToFind = 'Ф.И.О.'
$( "th:contains('"+itemToFind+"')" ).html('<input value="'+itemToFind+'" />')
```

If you want all `th` which have class `editable` to be replaced with input use the code below

```
 $( "th.editable" ).each( function() {
     $(this).html('<input value="'+$(this).text()+'" />')
 });
```

Comment: I Updated snippet on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/irider89/jsL28xno/6/
It works only for the first element.

Comment: You should repeat it for any Text you want to be replaced with an input, you must specify the text, do you want to do it for all of th?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have given an `id` to the `td` you want to turn editable.

1. Select all `td` with `id` "nameEditable"
2. For each of those:
3. Cache the text
4. Create an `input`
5. Assign the cached text to the `input`s `val`
6. Clear the `td` text
7. Append the created `input` to the `td`

It would be better if you give your button an `id`.

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    $("td#nameEditable").each(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var $tmpl = $("<input type='text' />");
        $tmpl.val(txt);
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($tmpl);
    });
});
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsL28xno/5/***

### Update:

If you want to search for particular text in `th` and then use that to convert that column to editable, then:

1. Search `th` containing the text
2. Store the index of that `th`
3. Use `nth-child` selector to select all `td` with the stored index (+1 actually)
4. Insert `input` as mentioned in the above code snippet

.

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    editColumn("Ф.И.О.");
    editColumn("Выбранная норма за месяц");
});

function editColumn(whichColumn) {
    var idx = $("table th:contains('" + whichColumn + "')").index() + 1;
    $('table td:nth-child(' + idx + ')').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var $tmpl = $("<input type='text' />");
        $tmpl.val(txt);
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($tmpl);        
    });
}
```

***Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/5rdq5s43/1/***

***Note 1***: *Instead of searching for text, you could directly use the column number*.

***Note 2***: *It is advisable to provide each `input` you add, a unique `id`. You can do that by using the `index` of the `each` function.*

Answer (score 0):

I would use nameEditable as class because you have multiple element with this marker on document and ended up with something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".triggeredit-card-list").click(function () {
        $('.nameEditable').each(function(index, item){
            var content = $(item).html();
            $(item).replaceWith('<input type="text" class="editable-table" name="editname" id="edittext" value="' + content + '" />');
        })
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsL28xno/8/)

```js
$(function () {
    $(".triggeredit-card-list").click(function () {
        $('.nameEditable').each(function(index, item){
            var content = $(item).html();
            $(item).replaceWith('<input type="text" class="editable-table" name="editname" id="edittext" value="' + content + '" />');
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="flip-scroll" class="table-responsive card-list-table">
    <table class="table table-custom">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Номер карты</th>
                <th>Ф.И.О.</th>
                <th>Дата выдачи</th>
                <th>Состояние</th>
                <th>Сумма на карте</th>
                <th>Категория</th>
                <th>Суточная норма</th>
                <th>Месячная норма</th>
                <th>Выбранная норма за месяц</th>
                <th>Вес карты</th>
                <th>Комментарий</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>5757427</td>
                <td class="nameEditable">Петров Иван Иванович 1</td>
                <td>25.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>Дизель</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>26</td>
                <td id="monthValue">1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>69594894</td>
                <td class="nameEditable">Константинопольский Яков Аристархович</td>
                <td>27.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5757427</td>
                <td class="nameEditable">Петров Иван Иванович</td>
                <td>25.12.2013</td>
                <td>Все</td>
                <td>3 300</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Комментарий</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-triggeredit triggeredit-card-list"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Редактировать</button>
```